# Equivalence Relations (Discrete Math)

Tags: relations

Hello I'm having trouble with this math problem on equivalence relations. 
Let X be any subset of the set of positive integers Z. Define a relation ~ on X as follows:

I have reflexive proven, having trouble with transitivity and symmetric.

Comment: The question is useless if you remove the definition of the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Symmetric-  }$If $a/b=2^k$ then $b/a=2^{-k}$

$\textbf{Transitive-}$ If $a/b=2^{k_1}$ and $b/c=2^{k_2}$ then $a/c=(a/b)(b/c)=2^{k_1+k_2}$

Comment: If you are satisfied, please don't forget to upvote and accept.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric if: $\frac{a}{b}=2^n$ then what does $\frac{b}{a}$ equall?

Transitive: Start by saying what you know

$$ \frac{a}{b}=2^n$$
and
$$ \frac{b}{c}=2^k$$

What can you say about $\frac{a}{c}$?